# Find a height based on angle of elevation and depression

Tags: trigonometry

To measure the height of a building, a man stands on another building facing it. From his window he sees the top of the first building with an angle of elevation of 30" and the bottom with an angle of depression of 45" °, the distance between the two buildings is 20 m, therefore the height of the first building in meters is A. 20√2 sin 75/sin 60° B. 20 tan 45+ 20 sin 30° C. 20 sin 75 °/sin 60° D. (20 √2 sin 45+ 20√2 sin 30°)/sin 60°

[My attempt][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpFiu.jpg

Knowing the height I then solve all the options until I got the one that matched my answer in the drawing.which result in the A. However I want to know if there was another way of doing it.trig

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: By the sine law, $\dfrac{AC}{\sin 75^\circ} = \dfrac{BC}{\sin60^\circ}$, which gives answer A.